# Elasticsearch get latest badge value for each user

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a index "candidate_ranking" having documents with following document structure. Each document of index has 1 candidate_id and there can be multiple documents with same candidate_id, but created_at field would be different for them. Here is sample of documents in my candidate_ranking index-

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SCa26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 118558,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-27T01:34:29.628550+00:00",
          "badge" : "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SSa26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 133354,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-27T02:11:35.811420+00:00",
          "badge" : "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Sia26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 148136,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-29T20:20:36.482066+00:00",
          "badge" : "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Sya26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 162916,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-29T21:05:03.985032+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TCa26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 177712,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-29T21:33:32.596613+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TSa26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 192999,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-29T22:20:24.942116+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Tia26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 225434,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-29T23:13:59.266074+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Tya26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 247169,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-30T00:16:04.077245+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "UCa26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 271179,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-30T01:19:59.803999+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate_ranking",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "USa26HgB0zUr7edEvDul",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 295537,
          "candidate_id" : 29492,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-30T02:23:42.077149+00:00",
          "badge" : null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This badge value can either be empty string or "1" or "2".

I am using this aggregation presently to get count of all users with both badge value 1 and 2

```
GET /candidate_ranking/_search
{
  "aggs": {
      "mega_mogul": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "badge.keyword", 
          "exclude": ["", "2"],
          "size": 500000
        }
      },
      "rising_mogul": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "badge.keyword", 
          "exclude": ["", "1"],
          "size": 500000
        }
      }
  }
}
```

My index is containing multiple document of each "candidate_id".
I want to make badge aggregation only for latest document for each candidate_id.
Something like sort or order by created_at field in descending order and then taking only top value for each candidate_id. Hence taking count of all candidates having latest badge as 1 or 2.

I tried doing this, but is not working

```
GET /candidate_ranking/_search
{
  "aggs": {
      "mega_mogul": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "badge.keyword", 
          "exclude": ["", "2"],
          "size": 500000,
          "order": {"created_at": "desc"}, 
          "top_hits": {"size":1}
        }
      },
      "rising_mogul": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "badge.keyword", 
          "exclude": ["", "1"],
          "size": 500000
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does each document have a unique `"candidate_id" ? Can you please share some more sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: And the `badge` value should be either 1 OR 2 ?

Comment: there can be multiple documents with same candidate_id.
badge value should be 1. I am suppose to take count of 1 and 2 separately, not the combined count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) along with [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) to achieve your required use case

**To get the count of buckets, you need to use [stats_bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html)**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 295537,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-30T02:23:42.077149+00:00",
  "badge": "1"
}
{
  "id": 271179,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-30T01:19:59.803999+00:00",
  "badge": "1"
}
{
  "id": 247169,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-30T00:16:04.077245+00:00",
  "badge": "1"
}
{
  "id": 225434,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-29T23:13:59.266074+00:00",
  "badge": null
}
{
  "id": 192999,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-29T22:20:24.942116+00:00",
  "badge": null
}
{
  "id": 177712,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-29T21:33:32.596613+00:00",
  "badge": null
}
{
  "id": 162916,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-29T21:05:03.985032+00:00",
  "badge": null
}
{
  "id": 148136,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-29T20:20:36.482066+00:00",
  "badge": "2"
}
{
  "id": 118558,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-27T01:34:29.628550+00:00",
  "badge": "2"
}
{
  "id": 133354,
  "candidate_id": 29492,
  "created_at": "2021-03-27T02:11:35.811420+00:00",
  "badge": "2"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "badge_1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "badge.keyword",
        "include": [
          "1"
        ],
        "size": 500000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "candidate_id",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "latestOrder": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_doc": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            },
            "latestOrder": {
              "max": {
                "field": "created_at"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "stats_1": {
          "stats_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "unique_id._count"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "badge_2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "badge.keyword",
        "include": [
          "2"
        ],
        "size": 500000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "candidate_id",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "latestOrder": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_doc": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            },
            "latestOrder": {
              "max": {
                "field": "created_at"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "stats_2": {
          "stats_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "unique_id._count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
    "aggregations": {
    "badge_2": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "unique_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 29492,
                "doc_count": 3,
                "latestOrder": {
                  "value": 1.617049236482E12,
                  "value_as_string": "2021-03-29T20:20:36.482000Z"
                },
                "top_doc": {
                  "hits": {
                    "total": {
                      "value": 3,
                      "relation": "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score": 1.0,
                    "hits": [
                      {
                        "_index": "67157371",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "2",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "id": 133354,
                          "candidate_id": 29492,
                          "created_at": "2021-03-27T02:11:35.811420+00:00",
                          "badge": "2"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "stats_2": {
            "count": 1,      // note this
            "min": 3.0,
            "max": 3.0,
            "avg": 3.0,
            "sum": 3.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "badge_1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "unique_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 29492,
                "doc_count": 3,
                "latestOrder": {
                  "value": 1.617071022077E12,
                  "value_as_string": "2021-03-30T02:23:42.077000Z"
                },
                "top_doc": {
                  "hits": {
                    "total": {
                      "value": 3,
                      "relation": "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score": 1.0,
                    "hits": [
                      {
                        "_index": "67157371",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "10",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "id": 295537,
                          "candidate_id": 29492,
                          "created_at": "2021-03-30T02:23:42.077149+00:00",
                          "badge": "1"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "stats_1": {
            "count": 1,       // note this
            "min": 3.0,
            "max": 3.0,
            "avg": 3.0,
            "sum": 3.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is still giving same result as before. I desire to get latest badge for each candidate_id. I am sure this is not the right result because I dont have the number of candidates in my db as it is reverting in above aggregation for both badge 1 and 2 separately. Again for some 123 candidate_id. If there are 5 documents for that candidate then I intent to pick the latest and increment the count against its badge value.

Comment: @RicheshChouksey please go through the search result, shown in the answer above (based on the index data as given in the answer above). Let me know if this is what you expect to get ?

Comment: No, The answer is incorrect. For above sample case I desire 1 as count for badge 1 as candidate_id is same in all documents. So when aggregating for badge 1 we will consider latest created_at for provided candidate_id and count only that particular document, ignoring other previous documents for that candidate_id with badge 1, if another candidate_id is there then we would be taking latest entry of that too for badge 1. Same for badge 2

Comment: @RicheshChouksey sorry for the late reply. Please check the updated search result and query. Now the count is 1 for badge 1 as well as for badge 2